# make failed, uncaught signal 11 error when installing Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

make failed, uncaught signal 11

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\Users\ryan1>jekyll -v
'jekyll' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, in the late hours of the night, the `jekyll` command is aliased to `hyde`. And of those times, sometimes it will respond to your request pleasantly and run as expected, but other times it can be quite unfriendly. When that happens, I usually wait until morning and then try again when it's behaving better.

That or the executable is missing from your path. Which is the case here? Who can say? But it's probably the first one.